# Using Ajax between two View in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We are try to do some table operations with using ajax. But we couldnt do it.

We have a table which lists all the contacts. Also we have a search button that filters all.

## SEARCH.CSHTML

```
  <div>
        <table class="sortable" id="contactTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ad Soyad</th>
                    <th>Ünvan</th>
                    <th>Ofis</th>
                    <th>Dahili Telefon</th>
                    <th nowrap>Cep Telefonu</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th nowrap>Ev Telefonu</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var contact in @Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @contact.displayName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @contact.title
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @contact.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @contact.telephoneNumber
                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            @contact.mobile
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @contact.mail
                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            @contact.homePhone
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

## INDEX.CSHTML

```
<div class="container" id="tableDiv">
<table class="sortable" id="contactTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ad Soyad</th>
            <th>Ünvan</th>
            <th>Ofis</th>
            <th>Dahili Telefon</th>
            <th nowrap>Cep Telefonu</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th nowrap>Ev Telefonu</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var contact in @Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @contact.displayName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @contact.title
                </td>
                <td>
                    @contact.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @contact.telephoneNumber
                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    @contact.mobile
                </td>
                <td>
                    @contact.mail
                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    @contact.homePhone
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## CREATE FUNCTION

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.givenName = collection["givenName"];
        newContact.sn = collection["sn"];
        newContact.title = collection["title"];
        newContact.physicalDeliveryOfficeName = collection["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"];

        if (collection["telephoneNumber"] != null && collection["telephoneNumber"] != "")
            newContact.telephoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(collection["telephoneNumber"]);

        newContact.mail = collection["mail"];
        newContact.mobile = collection["mobile"];

        string displayName = collection["givenName"] + " " + collection["sn"];
        newContact.displayName = displayName;
        newContact.cn = displayName;
        newContact.isIntegrated = true;

        if ((newContact.givenName != null && newContact.givenName != "") && ((newContact.sn != null && newContact.sn != "")))
        {
            PhoneDexContext context = new PhoneDexContext();
            context.Contacts.Add(newContact);
            context.SaveChanges();

            contactList.Add(newContact);
        }

        return View();
    }           
}
```

## SEARCH CLASS

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
    {
        Search searchItem = new Search();
        string inputName = collection["displayName"];
        string inputMail = collection["email"];
        string inputOffice = collection["office"];


        if (inputName != null)
            searchItem.fullName = inputName;
        if (inputMail != null)
            searchItem.email = inputMail;
        if (inputOffice != null)
            searchItem.office = inputOffice;
        if (collection["telephone"] != "")
            searchItem.telephoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(collection["telephone"]);

        IEnumerable<Contact> filteredContacts = contactList;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItem.fullName))
        {
            filteredContacts = filteredContacts.Where(c => c.displayName != null  && checkString(c.displayName,searchItem.fullName));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItem.email))
        {
            filteredContacts = filteredContacts.Where(c => c.mail != null && checkString(c.mail, searchItem.email));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItem.office))
        {
            filteredContacts = filteredContacts.Where(c => c.physicalDeliveryOfficeName != null && checkString(c.physicalDeliveryOfficeName, searchItem.office));
        }

        if (searchItem.telephoneNumber != null)
        {
            filteredContacts = filteredContacts.Where(c => c.telephoneNumber != null && c.telephoneNumber == searchItem.telephoneNumber);
        }

        return PartialView(filteredContacts);
    }
```

We cant reach the data with using this ajax code

```
 function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/Home/Search", true);
    var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    xhttp.send(form);
}
```

Comment: You have added jquery as a tag, why aren't you using it for the ajax call?

Comment: Where is the 'searchForm' ?